# If I draw a rectangle, then extrude it, will it be identical to a box?

Tags: 3dsmax

If I draw a rectangle, then extrude it, will it be identical to a box? I mean, will bottom face be closed as in box?

Comment: This question seems a bit out of place. Did you try it? Is there some particular behavior that happens that you do not expect? Is there some answer you're looking for to prove a point?

Comment: I tried it but am not so familar with 3ds max to diagnose the properties of bottom face. Please answer in the case you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not be identical to the Box primitive, as the result will be a Rectangle with an Extrude modifier.

It may have the same apparent geometry like a box, assuming that you toggle the flag to cap the beginning and end of the extrude.

The origin of the resulting object will be at the base, which may differ from where the origin of a box normally is.